# IMAP4 library syntax

Tags: python

Trying to figure out how this syntax works:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', searchLine, "ALL")
```

My first succesfull aproach was using the syntax for sorting the inbox , by:

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL")
```

While my actual target is to sort the inbox separately one by one. For this i used the first syntax described above, ofcourse without any success.

Some assist in explaining how this syntax works, would be appreciated.

Comment: What part of the syntax don't you understand? It's just calling a function with 3 arguments. The function returns a tuple, you assign them to two variables.

Comment: The problem is that "searchLine" returns all the mail in the inbox, and not the 1st one only. Its like the second argument is the same for both the syntaxes (e.g None = searchLine), i can post the whole code maybe it will clear some doubt @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not providing the search string properly. See the [IMAP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.4) for the syntax of the `SEARCH` command. It has to be followed by keywords that specify the searching criteria, and some of these keywords have parameters.

You have to specify where in the message you're searching for the search term.

```
result, data = mail.uid('search', 'TEXT', searchLine)
```

The `TEXT` keyword specifies that it should search in the message header and body for the value of `searchLine`.